# Looking for animation about a little girl and a boy who can shapeshift into a shark

Tags: story-identification, animation

I first watched this animation on Youtube several years ago;  4-5 is my best guess.

What I remember:

- The girl wore yellow and had either blue hair or eyes; or both
- The boy was an assailant trying to kill the girl
- On a ship, later an island, and then a ship again
- Vibrant colors
- Something really sad. I cried hysterically, I don't remember why. This is also the main reason why I am trying to find this animation
- I remember the boy could shift into a shark
- The girl was somewhere between 3-6 years old, and the boy was more teenager

Is there an animation that fits this description?

**Edit**: I think the boy's name was some color. I don't remember which color though.

Comment: It's not the The Adventures of Sharkboy and Lavagirl? Live action I think, rather than animated, but a lot of SX in there, that might give the impression of animation.

Comment: @bob1 No, that isn't it. It is a close match though . . .

Comment: is it a 3d or 2d animation?

Comment: @jo1storm 3-d animation

Comment: Check this one, it is from 4 years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2-nw0tBX9M

Comment: this one was three years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UT-mA673hLs

Comment: @jo1storm None of them are the one I'm looking for, but thank you, they both seem like good animations :)